# Can CAEmitterCell have vector based contents?

Tags: ios, particle-system, caemitterlayer, caemittercell

I want to use CALayers or another vector based drawing for the particles in my system. I need to zoom in with out pixelation.

I would like to do something like this

```
CALayer* layer = [CALayer layer];    
emitterCell.contents = (id)layer;
```